# How to redirect page to user with user prefered language when opening a browser

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

Django 1.9.6 i18n works perfect when I open the browser and change language.
But I want to save language and the other times when user comes it will be in his/her prefered language.
Now when I open the site it always redirect me to /en .I tried to change my settings and set

```
 LANGUAGE_CODE='ru'
```

or something else but it does not work here is my settings file

```
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
   LOGIN_URL=reverse_lazy('login')
   AUTH_USER_MODEL='custom.MyUser'
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'custom',
     'languages',
        ]

  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
      'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  ]

   ROOT_URLCONF = 'builtcustom.urls'
     WSGI_APPLICATION = 'builtcustom.wsgi.application'
     LANGUAGES=(
                ('en',_('ENGLISH')),
                ('fr',_('FRENCH')),
                ('cs', _('czech')),
                ('hy', _('ARMENIAN')),
                ('ru', _('RUSSIAN')),
                )
    LOCALE_PATHS = (
                        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),

                    )

 LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
 TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
 USE_I18N = True
 USE_L10N = True
 USE_TZ =False
```

How can i solve this problem and redirect to url with a language that I want(Dynamically selected from database)??

Answer (score 1):

For a particular url you an select language like this in Django.

```
from django.utils.translation import activate
activate('fr') # To use french
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#localized-names-of-languages).
You can easily get whatever language you want from the database and call activate on it. Make sure your the languages in database has same abbreviations as in Django.